# Appearance of items under header on onClick event in SectionedRecyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-transitions

In my android project I am using [SectionedRecyclerview](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter)
to Create headers in recyclerview. And I have also achieved to adding and removing items dynamically by improving code like below.

CODE :

```
      public class MyadapterNew extends StatelessSection {

ArrayList<String> data;

ArrayList<String> Hdata;

public MyadapterNew(int headerResourceId, int itemResourceId,ArrayList<String>data,ArrayList<String> hdata;) {
    super(headerResourceId, itemResourceId);
    this.data = data;
    this.Hdata=hdata;
}


class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView header;
    public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        header = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.header);

    }
}

class MyItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView filename;



    public MyItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        filename = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.filename);


    }
}

public void addItem(int position, String item) {
  this.data.add(position,item);
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
  this.data.remove(position);
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
    return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
    return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
}



@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;
    itemHolder.filename.setText(data.get(position));


}

@Override
public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindHeaderViewHolder(holder);
    HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
    headerHolder.Header.setText(Hdata.get(0));

}

@Override
public int getContentItemsTotal() {
    return data.size();

}
 }
```

What I want to do is,only all the headers should appear when activity starts, the items under each header should not appear. Whenever user click on header,Items under that particular header should appear(like drop down). If user click the same header again items should disappear. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the Expandable Section example [here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example4Fragment.java). Basically you should:

1) Add a boolean flag to your section class to control when it is expanded; In your case set it to 'false' as default as you don't want it to display items initially; [code here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example4Fragment.java#L64)

2) Change getContentItemsTotal method to return size 0 when section is not expanded; [code here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example4Fragment.java#L73-L76)

3) Implement setOnClickListener to expand your section in onBindHeaderViewHolder; [code here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example4Fragment.java#L111-L120)

Comment: Thank you very much. In my project there will be more than one header.There won't be equal number of items for each header. how to put items for each header?

Comment: I see you have methods addItem and removeItem in your MyadapterNew class, just call them :) You are also passing the the list of data to the constructor, so just pass different list of data per instance of MyadapterNew

Comment: Thank you very much. Please look at this problem   [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956323/sectionedrecyclerview-could-not-create-new-header-dynamically]