# sectionedrecyclerview: Could not create new header dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with two sliding tabs(fragments). I want to create a header for Recyclerview dynamically, so that the user will get a dialogBox with an edittext in it. As soon as user clicks OK after typing the header name in the edittext, the string gets passed from activity to fragment. I have succeeded in transferring header name from activity to fragment using interface. A method in fragment will receive that string.

Method:

```
          @Override
          public void setDatainfo(String datainfo) {
              Log.d("receivedset",datainfo);

              AddSection(datainfo);
          }
```

However, I need to use the received string to create a new header for the Recyclerview in that fragment tab, so it gets passed to AddSection() method. I have initialized the necessary classes already in onCreateView of that fragment. I simply need to do this in AddSection() method.

AddSection method:

```
   public void AddSection(String datainfo){
       MyadapterNew myadapterNew = new MyadapterNew(datainfo,getActivity(),R.layout.headerpond,R.layout.file_row_new,fDataset);

       Log.d("received",datainfo);
       sectionAdapter.addSection(myadapterNew);
       sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

It has to create a new header, but it is not creating one.

FragmentCode:

```
    public class tab1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements home.infopass {
        public ArrayList<String> fDataset = new ArrayList<>();
        private Context context;
        private SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter   sectionAdapter;

        RecyclerView fRecyclerView;
        @Override

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
            Log.d("tab1", "OncreateView");
            registerForContextMenu(v);

            sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

            MyadapterNew myadapterNew = new MyadapterNew("Pond1",getActivity(),R.layout.headerpond,R.layout.file_row_new,fDataset);

            sectionAdapter.addSection(myadapterNew);

            fRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_tab);
            fRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager fLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());

            fRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(fLayoutManager);
            fRecyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void setDatainfo(String datainfo) {
            Log.d("receivedset",datainfo);

            AddSection(datainfo);
        }
        public void AddSection(String datainfo){
            MyadapterNew myadapterNew = new MyadapterNew(datainfo,getActivity(),R.layout.headerpond,R.layout.file_row_new,fDataset);

            Log.d("received",datainfo);
            sectionAdapter.addSection(myadapterNew);
            sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    private class MyadapterNew extends StatelessSection {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("xyz", "abc", "xyhgz", "abygc"));

        String header;

        Context ctx;

        Boolean Expanded = false;
        public MyadapterNew(String header,Context ctx,int headerResourceId, int itemResourceId,ArrayList<String>data) {
            super(headerResourceId, itemResourceId);
            //this.data = data;
            this.ctx=ctx;
            this.header=header;
        }


        class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView header;
            public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                header = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.header);
            }
        }

    class MyItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView filename;

        private ProgressBar file_progressbar;

        private ImageView fileicon;

        private ImageView upldownstatus;

        private TextView filelength;


        public MyItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            filename = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.filename);

            file_progressbar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_progressbar);

            fileicon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.fileicon);

            upldownstatus = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.updownstatus);

            filelength = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.filelength);


        }
    }

    public void addItem(int position, String item) {


    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        this.data.remove(position);
        sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void addHeader(int position, String item) {
    }

    public void removeHeader(int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {

        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;
        itemHolder.filename.setText(data.get(position));
        final Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.fadeout);

        itemHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("CLICKED", "TRUE");

                itemHolder.itemView.setAnimation(animationFadeOut);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindHeaderViewHolder(holder);

        HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).header.setText(header);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Expanded=!Expanded;
                sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return Expanded? data.size():0;

    }

}


}
```

ERROR:

```
05-01 01:26:08.915 1571-1571/com.example.sandesh.filer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.sandesh.filer, PID: 1571
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.addSection(io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.Section)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.sandesh.filer.tab1.AddSection(tab1.java:197)
                                                                         at com.example.sandesh.filer.tab1.setDatainfo(tab1.java:90)
                                                                         at com.example.sandesh.filer.home$3.onClick(home.java:313)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AddSection method seems correct, are you sure the onCreateView method is not being fired after the AddSection was called? please check in your logs.

Comment: I don't know how I missed null pointer exception at `sectionAdapter.addSection(myadapterNew);` at this line in AddSection method. how to resolve this?

Comment: It looks like you are calling AddSection before the fragment draws its user interface. You should consider moving the line sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter(); from onCreateView to onCreate method of your fragment. More details about Fragment lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: it is a TabLayout, There will be two fragments(Tab1, and Tab2)sliding.Activity and two tab layouts gets created when apps starts at a time. It won't recreate again and again.So oncreate won't get called at all. As the sectionadapter already got initialised at the onCreateview very first time, can't we reuse it?

Comment: onCreate will always be called, give my suggestion a try

Comment: ok assuming that you didn't update the code and you are getting the same error, can you see "OncreateView" in your logs?

Comment: change this line to: private SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

Comment: The oncreateview not getting called after entering header name in edittext in dialogbox. I changed the way you said. This time I am not getting any error. But it's not creating header.

Comment: I have solved the issue and posted how I solved it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved My problem. As I suspected, Once the user entered header name, the header is passing into the fragment. However the string there is useless, as the sectionAdapter instance no longer exists to use  that string and create a header. I have to get instance of fragment which is already instantiated in the beginning(when app starts). So here is what I did to get it work.

```
      int position = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition
                      Fragment fragment = adapter.getFragment(tabLayout
                                        .getSelectedTabPosition());
                                if (fragment != null) {
                                    switch (position) {
                                        case 0:
                                            ((tab1) fragment).AddSection(data);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
```

I have used above code to send header string to the fragment. As I am using pager for my TabLayout, I have implemented getfragment method to get the instance of already instantiated fragment in my pagerAdapter.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    final Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    instantiatedFragments.put(position, new WeakReference<>(fragment));
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position, final Object object) {
    instantiatedFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

@Nullable
public Fragment getFragment(final int position) {
    final WeakReference<Fragment> wr = instantiatedFragments.get(position);
    if (wr != null) {
        return wr.get();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For more details, check this [Link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/12/android-activity-fragment-communication/), Hope it is useful for someone